# How to know where a certain macro is defined in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I currently have a visual studio project that uses DirectX. There are some macros in the code such as

```
__range(0, m_lBatchSize)  LONG  m_nBatched;
__field_ecount_opt(m_lBatchSize) IMediaSample  **      m_ppSamples;
```

I wanted to know which files these macros are defined in.  Normally in Visual Studio I would click goto definition and it would take me to the definitio. It is not taking me anywhere in this case. Does that feature work for macros ? Is there any way for me to find out where this macro is defined ?

Comment: F12 will go to a definition when the cursor is on the symbol. Does this not work in VS for macros?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

my trick is to put

```
#define __range FOO
```

in my code, the preprocessor will then say

```
__range already defined at xxxx.nn
```

Comment: Does the "already defined at xxxx.nn" output have to be enabled somehow? It seems with VS2015, it only prints an error "macro redefinition" and "see previous definition of `__range`. Doesn't appear to give you any originating file